# Enable and configure AWS Cognito Advanced Security Features via Terraform or Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, terraform

How do you enable the AWS Cognito Advanced Security Features option via Terraform or Cloudformation and then configure the Compromised Credentials option?

There doesn't appear to be anything listed on [the official doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html) for this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this as of now, neither in Terraform nor in CloudFormation, straightforward. Interesting enough, the feature is present in the aws-cli for quite some time now (almost a year since Nov 28, 2017).

What could work as a workaround though is : You can create a null resource and execute an aws-cli command using Terraform OR you can use `local-exec` and call aws-cli command there.

P.S. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SetRiskConfiguration.html) you can find more information on the cli command for advanced security features.

Comment: That is disappointing but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Really frustrating that there is nothing that helps direct a developer from "Advanced Security Features" to "SetRiskConfiguration". Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the past Cognito Advanced Security features could not be set via CloudFormation, but it is now possible. See the [AWS::Cognito::UserPoolRiskConfigurationAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolriskconfigurationattachment.html) resource.

And for Compromised Credentials, that is set in the CompromisedCredentialsRiskConfiguration section.